# Cannot Roundtrip DateTime Format

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, format

I convert a DateTime to a string using a custom format:

```
var s = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss");
```

Now, when I try to reverse it:

```
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss");
```

I get an exception about the string not being in a valid format. I even tried to pass CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, but no luck.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can not reproduce the error with invariant culture...

Comment: I can't reproduce this as well. It'll also be helpful if you tagged your question with the correct programming language (namely, [tag:c#]), as .NET isn't a programming language.

Comment: Since `DateTime.ParseExact` does not have an override that takes two string arguments, it appears you're not showing your original code.  One problem is that you are using the hour specifier hh without an AM/PM designator.  Try using HH instead, or add an AM/PM designator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had mistakenly forgotten the last parameter to ParseExact, which whould be CultureInfo.InvariantCulture. In the end, however, the problem was not having HH instead of hh.

Answer (score 3):

If you use ToString method with one argument, then it uses CurrentCulture as format provider that can change the "/" symbol to specific for your culture ("." for example). 
If InvariantCulture is acceptable for you, try to use this code:

```
var s = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Or the other way around: use `'/'` instead of a plain `/`, to always use a slash (so `"yyyy'/'MM'/'dd hh:mm:ss"`)